# Coloring clusters

Tags: r, machine-learning, colors, data-visualization, cluster-analysis

I am using the following code which performs the SOM (Self Organizing Map, also called the Kohonen Network) machine learning algorithm to visualize some data. Then, I use a clustering algorithm (I select 8 clusters) on the visualization:

```
#load library
library(tidyverse)
library(kohonen)
library(GGally)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(mlr)

#load data
data(flea)
fleaTib <- as_tibble(flea)

#define SOM grid
somGrid <- somgrid(xdim = 5, ydim = 5, topo = "hexagonal",
neighbourhood.fct = "bubble", toroidal = FALSE)

#format data
fleaScaled <- fleaTib %>%
select(-species) %>%
scale()

#perform som
fleaSom <- som(fleaScaled, grid = somGrid, rlen = 5000,
alpha = c(0.05, 0.01))

par(mfrow = c(2, 3))
plotTypes <- c("codes", "changes", "counts", "quality",
"dist.neighbours", "mapping")
walk(plotTypes, ~plot(fleaSom, type = ., shape = "straight"))

getCodes(fleaSom) %>%
as_tibble() %>%
iwalk(~plot(fleaSom, type = "property", property = .,
main = .y, shape = "straight"))

# listing flea species on SOM

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
nodeCols <- c("cyan3", "yellow", "purple", "red", "blue", "green", "white", "pink")
plot(fleaSom, type = "mapping", pch = 21,
bg = nodeCols[as.numeric(fleaTib$species)],
shape = "straight", bgcol = "lightgrey")

# CLUSTER AND ADD TO SOM MAP ---- (8 clusters)
clusters <- cutree(hclust(dist(fleaSom$codes[[1]], 
                               method = "manhattan")), 8)

somClusters <- map_dbl(clusters, ~{
    if(. == 1) 3
    else if(. == 2) 2
    else 1
}
)


plot(fleaSom, type = "mapping", pch = 21, 
     bg = nodeCols[as.numeric(fleaTib$species)],
     shape = "straight",
     bgcol = nodeCols[as.integer(somClusters)])

add.cluster.boundaries(fleaSom, somClusters)
```

[image]

But in the above plot, only 3 colors are shown instead of 8.

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `somClusters` with `clusters` in the definition of the background color in the last plot. The main issue is that you defined `somClusters` to have three values, not 8.  If you use that to index the vector of colors, it will only have three colors.

```
plot(fleaSom, type = "mapping", pch = 21, 
     bg = nodeCols[as.numeric(fleaTib$species)],
     shape = "straight",
     bgcol = nodeCols[as.integer(clusters)])

add.cluster.boundaries(fleaSom, somClusters)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! just a question : is it possible to skip this line of code "nodeCols <- c("cyan3", "yellow", "purple", "red", "blue", "green", "white", "pink") " and automatically select different colors for the clusters? thank you for all your help!

Comment: You need to supply colors somehow.  You could use an `RColorBrewer` palette or even `rainbow(8)[as.integer(clusters)]` if you wanted to.  This is a base R plot, so it's not like ggplot where you can just tell it what variable defines the colors and it will pick them for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Do you mean like this: nodeCols <- rainbow(8)[as.integer(clusters)] ??

Comment: No, you could just replace `bgcol = nodeCols[as.integer(clusters)])` with `bgcol = rainbow(8)[as.integer(clusters)]`